# HashMap Obtener si existe la clave a partir de posibles candidatos en Java

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente variable para guardar propiedades con su `clave:valor`

```
Map<String, String> properties = new LinkedHashMap<>();

properties.put("lat","48.756189");
properties.put("longitude","94.218750");
properties.put("name","Gengis Kan");
```

Me gustaria obtener con una función si existe la clave a partir de unos candidatos por ejemplo `latitude|lat|y` si encuentra alguno por orden devuelve `true`

Para separar los candidatos tengo

```
String candidatesStr = "latitude|lat|y"
String[] candidates = candidatesStr.split("|");
```

Me falta obtener las claves existentes en `properties` y comparar con algun candidato si concide devuelve `true`

Como complemento seria obtener de los candidatos el nombre del primero que se ha econtrado para luego poder obtener su valor `properties.get(candidato_encontrado)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Itera sobre el hasmamp de la siguiente

```
function boolean verifyCandidates(String[] candidates) {
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> prop: properties.entrySet()) {
        String key = prop.getKey();
        if(Arrays.asList(candidates).contains(key)){ 
           return true;
        }
    }
   return false;
}
```

Si quieres obtener el valor del que está iterando en vez de devolver un booleano devuelve un string con el nombre

```
function String verifyCandidates(String[] candidates) {
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> prop: properties.entrySet()) {
      String key = prop.getKey();
      if(Arrays.asList(candidates).contains(key)) {
         return key;
      }
    }
    return "";
}
```

O puedes devolver de una vez el valor

```
function String verifyCandidates(String[] candidates) {
     for(Map.Entry<String, String> prop: properties.entrySet()) {
        String key = prop.getKey();
        if(Arrays.asList(candidates).contains(key)) {
           return prop.getValue();
        }
     }
     return "";
}
```

Comment: NO debe ser <String, HashMap> ya que se tiene llave y valor como String. Los for() siempre van a retornar true, ya que obviamente revisaría en el Map los elementos =(.

Comment: Gracias por las correcciones, ya edité la respuesta.

Comment: Si parece que ahora ya funciona como es debido

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente la forma correcta de separar los elementos de un String mediante un pipe y generar un array es usando , `.split("\\|")` , de esta forma:

```
String candidatesStr = "latitude|lat|name";
String[] candidates = candidatesStr.split("\\|");
```

---

De esta forma podrías revisar si alguna clave existe:

```
Map<String, String> properties = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        properties.put("lat","48.756189");
        properties.put("longitude","94.218750");
        properties.put("name","Gengis Kan");

        String candidatesStr = "latitude|lat|name";
        String[] candidates = candidatesStr.split("\\|");

        for(Map.Entry<String, String> prop: properties.entrySet()) {
            String key = prop.getKey();
            if(Arrays.asList(candidates).contains(key)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Se encuentra: " + key);
            }else{
                Log.i(TAG, "NO se encuentra: " + key);
            }
        }
```

Si deseas un método para saber si alguno de los candidatos se encuentra sería:

```
public boolean checkCandidatos(String[] candidates, Map<String, String> properties) {
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> prop: properties.entrySet()) {
        String key = prop.getKey();
        if(Arrays.asList(candidates).contains(key)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Si deseas un método para obtener el nombre del primer candidato que se encuentre en el String

```
public String checkCandidato(String[] candidates, Map<String, String> properties) {
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> prop: properties.entrySet()) {
        String key = prop.getKey();
        if(Arrays.asList(candidates).contains(key)) {
            return key;
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Gracias, con las expresiones regulares siempre me hago un lio,

Comment: @Webserveis en realidad esta no sería una REGEX, lo que sucede es que este carácter pipe "|" es un caracter especial debe estar "escapado" para que pueda funcionar como separador. Lo que no es necesario con otros caracteres como ",","-", etc.

Answer (score 1):

Añado otras soluciones que he ido encontrando

Para checkear si hay un candidato disponible

```
public boolean hasProperty(String[] candidates) {
    for (String candidate : candidates) {
        if (properties.containsKey(candidate)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Para obtener el valor de un candidato si existe

```
public String getProperty(String[] candidates) {
    for (String candidate : candidates) {
        if (properties.containsKey(candidate)) {
            return properties.get(candidate);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Para obtener el candidato

```
public String getCandidate(String[] candidates) {
    for (String candidate : candidates) {
        if (properties.containsKey(candidate)) {
            return candidate;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```